# htaccess redirect subfolders to domain

Tags: .htaccess, laravel, redirect, dns, subdirectory

i bought a domain (e.g. mydomain.com) on some hoster. Because i had good experience with the webspace of an another hoster, i took it there. I installed a forwarding on the hoster where i got the domain. From the hoster of my webspace i got an URL to access it like: www42.mydomain.some-server.com.

So the forwarding is like mydomain.com to www42.mydomain.some-server.com.
When i access mydomain.com tge forwarding works perfekt, i see the application running on the webspace with the correct URL.
If i click now any link, (e.g. for signup) i'm redirected to www42.mydomain.some-server.com/signup.
But i want it to be mydomain.con/signup.

So i would need a redirect of any subfolders from www42.mydomain.some-server.com to mydomain.com.
I tested once a redirection of all requests to mydomain.com but it ended in an infinite loop :D
How do i do that?

For your information:
The application is build with laravel 5.0 and there is the standard htaccess available. If you want to, i can post it here.

Comment: What kind of "forwarding" did you put on your domain? HTTP 301? CNAME DNS entry? And on your website, are the links hardcoded to `www42.mydomain.some-server.com`, or are they actually relative ones?

Comment: It says it's an URL-Hiding forwarding on my domain hoster. In the application itself i'm working with relative ones. So for signup it's <a href='/signup'> [...]

Comment: If `dig` is available, try running `dig mydomain.com CNAME` and see of the response contains an `;; ANSWER SECTION` or not.

Comment: since dig is not available i used digwebinterface.com and there isn't ;; ANSWER SECTION

Comment: I think redirecting should to the trick, am i right? Redirrcting everything from www42.mydomain.some-server.com/* to mydomain.com/*

Comment: This will almost certainly result in an infinite loop. I suggest you just get a CNAME record set up in your DNS zone for mydomain.com, pointing it to www42.mydomain.some-server.com. I still don't know how the redirection is currently done, but it doesn't seem clean to me.

Comment: Yes thank you very much! Indeed it ended up in an infinite loop and setting up an CNAME record just worked out fine for me! Thank you very much :-)